# How to deliver a gem with GTK3?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, gtk3

How can I make an independent gem once I have completed a development? do I need to deliver msys2 too?

My environment:

- windows 10
- ruby 2.4.5
- my_gem depend on [gtk3](https://rubygems.org/gems/gtk3/versions/3.4.0) gem
- [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put the question directly to the GTK3 developers.

[here is their answer.](https://github.com/ruby-gnome/ruby-gnome/issues/1306)

Which means that if you choose to use GTK3 today with Ruby, you have to:

- Deliver MSYS2 and Ruby with your GEM (more than 1GB package !).
- Deliver your gem and tell users to install themselves msys2 (with updates) and ruby and your gem with dependencies.